# Disable volume control noise on mac book pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, audio

When I hit F11 or F12 (volume up and volume down) I get the volume control overlay; the volume increases or decreases; and the machine makes an "SQUICK SQUICK SQUICK" noise.

How do I keep the functionality of the keys but stop them making that noise?

(Mac Book Pro with Snow Leopard)

Comment: I have no idea what tags should go on this, so please suggest or edit them!! thanks.

Comment: That dang SQUICK sound annoyed the heck out of me, too. I turned it off a long time ago!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can change this in System Preferences.

Go to the Sound pane, and uncheck the `Play feedback when volume is changed` checkbox.

[image]

Also, if you want to not play the sound for a given change (a one-off thing), hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> and change the volume.
This will also play the sound if it's turned off.

Comment: A little off-topic, but you can also do micro adjustments to the volume by holding down both shift and option while hitting the volume keys.  (Removed in Lion, unfortunately)

Comment: They must have added 1/4 adjustments back into ML, because it works for me.